# When Peace Domain's Emboldening Bond feature specifies a number of creatures equal to your proficiency bonus, can you choose fewer than that number?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

In the Peace Domain subclass found in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, the cleric gains the 1st level feature Emboldening Bond which states, in part:

> As an action, you choose a number of willing creatures within 30 feet of you (this can include yourself) **equal to your proficiency bonus**.

(emphasis mine)

My question is this: Can you choose a number of willing creatures that is lesser than your proficiency bonus? For example, if I am a 10th level Peace Domain cleric with a proficiency bonus of +4, could I choose to affect only three creatures with my Emboldening Bond feature? Or must I choose four creatures, and if I can't do so then I can't use the feature?

In my searching, many other features use the wording "up to a number equal to..." to suggest that you can choose lesser numbers than the specified amount. The lack of such wording here makes me think that you must choose, as it says, a number equal to your proficiency bonus, no more and no less. Such a rule would seem odd to me, so I am curious if I've missed a rule that clarifies this.

Comment: Welcome to the stack SnowMunkey, take the [tour] when you have moment. I’ve closed this as a duplicate, as this same question has been asked before about a different feature with the same troublesome language.